# django orm queryset - how to perform sql query MIN/MAX FILTER

Tags: sql, django, filter, orm, max

I am trying to get help to create django ORM queryset for the particular sql statement (you can also run it here)
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=31c9431d6753e2fdd8df37bbc1869e88

In particular to this question, I am more interested in the line that consist of:

```
MIN(created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 1) as min_time_in,
MAX(created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 2) as max_time_out
```

Here is the whole sql if possible to convert to django ORM queryset

```
SELECT 
    created_at::date as created_date,
    company_id,
    employee_id,
    MIN(created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 1) as min_time_in,
    MAX(created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 2) as max_time_out
FROM
   timerecord
where date(created_at) = '2020-11-18' and employee_id = 1
GROUP BY created_date, company_id, employee_id
ORDER BY created_date, employee_id
```

Comment: Can you add your models? the Django models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`aggregate()`**--(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate) method or ([**`annotate()`**--(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) method) to get the result. For that, you must use the [**`Min()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#min) and [**`Max()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#max) database functions along with the ***`filter`*** parameter.

```
from django.db.models import Min, Q, Max

agg_response = TimeRecord.objects.aggregate(
    min_time_in=Min("created_at", filter=Q(activity_type=1)),
    max_time_out=Max("created_at", filter=Q(activity_type=2)),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The original query:

```
SELECT 
    created_at::date as created_date,
    company_id,
    employee_id,
    MIN(created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 1) as min_time_in,
    MAX(created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 2) as max_time_out
FROM
   timerecord
where date(created_at) = '2020-11-18' and employee_id = 1
GROUP BY created_date, company_id, employee_id
ORDER BY created_date, employee_id;
```

is an example of [conditional/selective aggregation](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter). The syntax above is available in PostgreSQL/SQLite.

It could be easily rewritten using CASE expression as:

```
SELECT 
    created_at::date as created_date,
    company_id,
    employee_id,
    MIN(CASE WHEN activity_type = 1 THEN created_at::time END)as min_time_in,
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity_type = 2 THEN created_at::time END) as max_time_out
FROM
   timerecord
where date(created_at) = '2020-11-18' and employee_id = 1
GROUP BY created_date, company_id, employee_id
ORDER BY created_date, employee_id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8aefee713a3ffd8ddf25655f3d62edc6)**

Which is supported by any modern RDBMS and it is supported by Django:

> [conditional-aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation)
>
> What if we want to find out how many clients there are for each account_type? We can nest conditional expression within aggregate functions to achieve this:
>
> ```
> Client.objects.aggregate(
> ...     regular=Count('pk', filter=Q(account_type=Client.REGULAR)),
> ...     gold=Count('pk', filter=Q(account_type=Client.GOLD)),
> ...     platinum=Count('pk', filter=Q(account_type=Client.PLATINUM)),
> ... )
> ```
>
> This aggregate produces a query with the SQL 2003 **FILTER WHERE** syntax on databases that support it
>
> ...
>
> On other databases, this is emulated using a CASE statement